# ValueError: Length of passed values is 0, index implies 11?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have a simple code like that, but unfortunately, I couldn't fix this length error. Can someone help me with a small explanation?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL='https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/'
response=requests.get(URL)
soup= BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
columns=['#','Name','Symbol','Market Cap','Price','Circulating Supply','Volume 24h','1h %','24h %','7d %','Notes']

table=soup.table


df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
trs=table.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [td.text.replace('\n','') for td in tds]
    df =df.append(pd.Series(row,index=columns),ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv('cryptopr.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: fixed with table changing

Comment: post your answer for the question asked above. so other users will found it helpful during search for same issue

Comment: When I use table=soup.table it doesn't count the number of columns but I used table=soup.table.tbody and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the entire table to csv so you might as well just use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/')[0]
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\cryptopr.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False)
```